# What is the origin of humans in Hinduism or Sanatana Dharma?

Tags: human

What is the origin of humans in Hinduism or Sanatana Dharma?

Hinduism is not based on stories or myths. Its other way around here. The facts are being told as stories and mean heads misinterpret it as myths